# Send email to revision editor instead of node author

Tags: email, drupal, drupal-7, token, drupal-rules

I am currently using the Workbench Moderation module to allow pieces of content to be moderated and go through an approval process before being published. This all works great. Part of my process is to send an email to a user when their edited content has been approved/published. I currently have a Rule setup to where when a node gets published and it's under Moderation an email gets sent to the author of the node saying that the node was published. This is fine except for the fact that sometimes we have people editing someone else's content. In other words "Bob" creates a basic page and it gets published and he is the author. Now months down the road, "Susie" is tasked with editing Bobs page. She creates a new draft, sends it for review and a manager publishes it. The problem is that Bob gets the email that it was published and Susie has no idea that her edits were published and are now made live. I was looking in the Tokens in my Rule for the email that gets sent out when something is published and I could not find something that made sense as far as sending it to the Revision author as opposed to the original author. Is this even possible?

Comment: Check this: [Assigning revision owner when moderating backwards with Workbench](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/45114/12163)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, Erich?  The thread in the comment is a different type of problem...

Comment: No,unfortunately, I never did figure this one out. It's still an issue. We've just dealt with it this whole time.

Answer (score 0):

I really wanted this functionality too, and just managed by doing the following.

I created the tiniest custom module, containing nothing but the code from Comment #4 (which is just a small revision to the code from the previous comment) on this drupal.org thread: https://www.drupal.org/node/1730000.

It works, and now my revision authors can be notified when their page changes are published!